# Split ArrayFormula throwing #valueerror when data added to cells in range

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

Sorry for poor formatting ahead of time.

I have a Google Sheet that collects responses from a Form. What I am trying to do is take the URLs that are made from the file upload question on the form and split them into individual URLs in the same row. I had this working without issue previously and now when making a new sheet, the formula I am using is not working and giving me unexpected errors or data. Can't embed photos yet so links below.

[Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eZEZ.png)
[Value Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEiHQ.png)

The formula will copy data from the reference cell if there is no comma, but if a comma is added to any cell in the column, the entire formula stops working. I am really not sure what the problem is as I said this worked just fine previously. Thanks in advance, I've been at this longer than I care to admit and I assume this is a simple problem that I have overlooked.

Comment: I encourage you to share a link to a copy of your spreadsheet. You say in your post, "I assume this is a simple problem," but it is not. It will require complex formula development. And if a volunteer contributor here were to choose to invest the time to develop such a formula or formulas, they would need to have access to the actual data and layout. You would not need to have this spreadsheet copy connected to your form. Just be sure to include, say, 3 to 5 rows of realistic data in the form intake sheet in such a way that the problem/goal is represented clearly.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you encountered such issue is because you are trying to create an array with mismatched number of columns.

Based on your sample scenario, when you used `={"File1";arrayformula(iferror(split(Q2:Q,",")))}` while your column `Q2:Q` data doesn't have a comma, arrayformula will return 1 column results. Row1 column count and the array formula result's column count matches.

But if `Q2:Q` data contains comma, arrayformula will return multiple column results which doesn't match in your row 1 column count

**You can use this formula in `cell R1`:**

```
=arrayformula(iferror(split({"File1,File2,File3,File4,File5,File6";Q2:Q},",")))
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The problem is this sheet is for a Google Form, so every time a response it added a new row is inserted above the formula, defeating the purpose of what I am trying to do. I had this working on my previous sheet in the header cell and am kicking myself for not looking at it before it was deleted, but I know it is possible.

Comment: Can you tell me what is the maximum possible file column?

Comment: Maximum columns would be 6

Comment: I updated the answer. Please let me know if you encountered an issue

Comment: Thank you for the help with this. This still suffers from the same problem in that when a new form response comes in it inserts a new row at the top but the formula does not apply to the new row.

Comment: Please share a sample form and a sample sheet. Its weird that the new data was added at the top